# lock wait timout in InnoDb

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

I have created a mysql table with (date,name,id,money_spent)columns having (date,name,id) as the primary key (since this combination is always unique) and InnoDb is the storage engine .

date - Date datatype,
name - varchar(30),
id - varchar(100),

I have a logic where in multiple update queries are fired in parallel . For Eg (considering these 2 for now )

T1 :

```
 update test_database.users set money_spend = 1000
     where date between "2020-01-01" and "2020-01-10"
       and name = "John";
```

T2 :

```
update test_database.users set money_spend = 1005
     where date between "2020-01-01" and "2020-01-10"
       and name = "Tammy";
```

Running these 2 Transaction in parallel causes T2 to timeout because of the lock acquired by T1.

transaction isolation level - repeatable read isolation level

InnoDb Engine Status

```
LOCK WAIT 19543 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 1407774 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 105402, OS thread handle 0x2ba11d68a700, query id 16862373 10.11.3.212 connect-dev Sending data
update test_database.users set money_spend = 1005 where date between "2020-01-01" and "2020-01-10" and name = "Tammy";
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 2 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 154606 page no 243093 n bits 78 index `PRIMARY` of table `test_database`.`users` trx id 44023639357 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 78 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 30; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len=3; bufptr=0x2b9fea4e2d5e; hex= 8fc95b; asc   [;;
 1: len=8; bufptr=0x2b9fea4e2d61; hex= 4170706e65787573; asc John;;
 2: len=8; bufptr=0x2b9fea4e2d69; hex= 3230393835373832; asc 20985782;;
 3: len=6; bufptr=0x2b9fea4e2d71; hex= 000a3f47ff22; asc   ?G ";;
 4: len=7; bufptr=0x2b9fea4e2d77; hex= 0f011040350d5b; asc    @5 [;;
```

Looking at the innoDb status it looks like T2 is trying to acquire a lock on the record having "John" as the name but since records with "John" as the name are already locked by T1 , T2 times out .

Question : Since InnoDb supports row level locking shouldn't transaction(T1) acquire a lock on only the records having date between "2020-01-01" and "2020-01-10" and name as "John".Why is it giving a time out for the T2 transaction since the name part of the index is different (T2 is having "Tammy" as the name)

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: @Shadow only primary (date,name,id)  . Dont have any secondary .

Comment: is date, name, and id the exact order of the fields in the index?

Comment: @Shadow Yep this is the exact order

Comment: If you run explain on both queries, do the explain results indicate that the primary key is used in the updates?

Comment: Yep it says primary is getting used.@Shadow anything to do with between clause on Date datatype ?

Comment: it seems as if the name part of the index was ignored in the locking. What does the key length say in the explains?

Comment: What does `id` look like?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN`.  Sometimes important details are left out when the full text is not presented.

Comment: How big is the table?

Comment: @Shadow key_len comes out to be 3.

Comment: Then it only uses the date part of the key (date data type is 3 bytes long), so @RickJames' answer should do it

Answer (score 2):

Rearrange the PK to `PRIMARY KEY(name, date, id)`.  This way, all the rows needed (in either query) will be adjacent in the table.  That is more efficient than having the rows scattered (with `(date, name, ...)`).

Speeding up the queries will help one query finish before another one threatens to conflict with it.

Having the rows consecutive avoids some "gap locking" situations.  (I don't know if this is relevant here, but it seems to be.)

The column tested with `=` needs to come *before*` the range test.

More indexing tips: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

If `id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then the pattern is "let's put some columns first in the PK in order to speed up some queries, then tack `id` on the end to make sure it is unique.  (I don't know if that is what you are doing; but it is not relevant to the immediate discussion.)

Comment: Can you add a reference from mysql documentation or performance blog to this answer? Would be nice to understand how range lookups influence the index usage!

Comment: @Shadow - I doubt if my simple one-sentence Rule of Thumb is explicitly stated in the docs.  Meanwhile, my blog is based on how indexing and searching works.  (So, I will grant you that my blog is not a "performance blog".)